# How can I call a view from another database that refers to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 databases:

- database_1: (Production DB) with one Table: `dbo.products`
- database_2: (Archive DB) with one View refers to database_1: `dbo.database_1_v`
- database_3: (Local DB) contains nothing, just call the view from DB2: `select * from database2.dbo.database_1_v`

If I am in database_2 and I call the view `dbo.database_1_v`, it works fine. I have access on database_2 to database_1. Unfortunately if I am in database_3 I cannot call the view from database_2 because the access is denied to database_1.

```sql
-- Step 1: Create the first database and table
-- To start, create the first database called database_1:
CREATE DATABASE database_1;

-- Next, create a table called "products" (with a dbo schema):
CREATE TABLE database_1.dbo.products (
    product_id int primary key,
    product_name nvarchar(50)
)


-- Then, insert 5 records into the "products’ table:
INSERT INTO database_1.dbo.products (product_id, product_name)
VALUES
(1, 'Laptop'),
(2, 'Tablet'),
(3, 'Monitor'),
(4, 'Printer'),
(5, 'Keyboard')


-- Step 2: Create the second database and view
-- Now create the second database called database_2:
CREATE DATABASE database_2

--Then, create a view called "database_1_v" (with a dbo schema):
CREATE VIEW database_1_v 
AS
 SELECT product_id, product_name
 FROM database_1.dbo.products;
)


-- Step 3: Create the second database and view
-- Now create the third database called database_3:
CREATE DATABASE database_3

-- Verify view records from DB 2
SELECT * FROM database_2.dbo.database_1_v
```

Comment: This works fine as long as the databases are all on the same server and your user has rights/permissions to access each database from the calling context.

Comment: I'm guessing the Local DB isn't on the same server?

Comment: *"database_2 has access to database_1"* This statement doesn't make sense; databases don't have access to each other `LOGIN`s have mapped `USER`s in databases, and it's the `USER` that has permissions in the database.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller so long as they aren't Azure hosted - cross-database queries are not supported on Azure

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I corrected the text @Larnu. I think the locale DB will not run on the same server. I forgot to ask which DB should run on which server. I will come back tomorrow with the answer. But basically, if all 3 were running on the same server and the user had permission on all 3, everything should work. (so long as they aren't Azure hosted)

Comment: If databases are all on the same instance, and the `LOGIN` the person is using has a mapped `USER` with the needed permissions on all 3 databases, then they will be able to use the `VIEW`s, @RolandTömösközi . If the person is saying that they can reference the object in `database1` via a `VIEW` in `database2` but *can't* via a `VIEW` in `database3` (again, all same instance), that suggests that you have cross database chaining enabled between db1 and db2 and they share the same owners,  and db3 doesn't have it enabled, or it does have db chaining but the owner differs.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan that is correct for azure, although you can use external table mapping for that which works very well

Comment: @ChrisSchaller ahhh, that's probably a better way of doing it than the remote execute approach we took at the last place I worked.

Comment: Ok guys, so I have more details. All databases run on one server and this is not on Azure. In the first level (prod) there are multiple databases. On the third level (local) there are multiple apps. To get a better overview, which app goes to which DB, I would create an intermediate database `database_2`. This way it would be easier to see which application is accessing which database. With the admin rights I can access all 3 DB (in the example). Thanks! But there is another problem: Not every user/application should access for all Tables from the `database_3`. How can I control that?

Comment: There are a few solutions to managing user security across databases, but that is another question and better suited for [dba.se]